# Create a list of dictionaries with a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Good morning,

I am learning how to work with list and dictionaries, so I have the next code:

```
 `import os
 import urllib.request
 import math

url1 =     'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aakashns/257f6e6c8719c17d0e498ea287d1a386/raw/7def9ef4234ddf0bc82f855ad 67dac8b971852ef/loans1.txt'

os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True) #Crea una carpeta llamada 'data'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url1,'./data/datos1.txt')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url2,'./data/datos2.txt')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url3,'./data/datos3.txt')

with open ('./data/datos1.txt') as file1:
   file1_lines=file1.readlines()

   print("NUESTRA LISTA\n")

   print(file1_lines)

#------CONVERTIMOS LOS VALORES EN UNA LISTA-----

   print("\nLimpiamos e individualizamos los valores de la lista:\n")

   def parse_values(data_line):
       values = []
       for item in data_line.strip().split(','):
           if item == '':
               values.append(0.0)
           else:
               try:
                   values.append(float(item))
               except ValueError:
                   values.append(item)
       return values

   contador=0
   file1_full=[]

   while contador<len(file1_lines):

    #print(parse_values(file1_lines[contador]))
       file1_full.append(parse_values(file1_lines[contador]))

       contador=contador+1

   print(file1_full) #Esto es una lista con todas las listas de cada conjunto de valores

   headers=file1_full[0]

   print("\n")

   print("ENCABEZADOS:\n")

   print(headers)
    
   file1_full.pop(0)

   print("\n")
   print("LISTA SIN ENCABEZADOS:\n")
   print(file1_full)

   print("\n")
   print("CONVERTIMOS CADA LINEA EN UN DICCIONARIO:\n")

   dic_result={}
   list_result=[]

   def dictionary(data_list):
    
       for header, value in zip(headers,data_list):
           dic_result[header]=value

       print(dic_result)

   contador2=0

   while contador2<len(file1_lines):

       try:
           dictionary(file1_full[contador2])
           list_result.append(dic_result)
           contador2=contador2+1
        
       except IndexError:
           break
        
   print("\n")
   print("CONVERTIMOS TODO EN UNA LISTA DE DICCIONARIOS")
   print(list_result)`
```

It basically download some data from a URL, clean it and converts it into a list, and in the bottom, combines the headers and the values into dictionaries with the function 'dictionary'

Then I applied a while loop into this function to all the diferent lines and the result of each line is a dictionary.

The problem is that I can not convert all this dictionaries into a single list of dictionaries.

The result I am looking for is:

```
`[{'amount': 100000.0, 'duration': 36.0, 'rate': 0.08, 'down_payment': 20000.0},
  {'amount': 200000.0, 'duration': 12.0, 'rate': 0.1, 'down_payment': 0.0},
  {'amount': 628400.0, 'duration': 120.0, 'rate': 0.12, 'down_payment': 100000.0},
  {'amount': 4637400.0, 'duration': 240.0, 'rate': 0.06, 'down_payment': 0.0},
  {'amount': 42900.0, 'duration': 90.0, 'rate': 0.07, 'down_payment': 8900.0},
  {'amount': 916000.0, 'duration': 16.0, 'rate': 0.13, 'down_payment': 0.0},
  {'amount': 45230.0, 'duration': 48.0, 'rate': 0.08, 'down_payment': 4300.0},
  {'amount': 991360.0, 'duration': 99.0, 'rate': 0.08, 'down_payment': 0.0},
  {'amount': 423000.0, 'duration': 27.0, 'rate': 0.09, 'down_payment': 47200.0}]`
```

I tried to append the result of the function 'dictionary' into the empty list 'list_result' but what it does is including the same dictionary over and over until the loop stops.

Can´t find out what I am doing wrong. Could you please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Now it's too much code inside the `with`. You should only include the code that reads the file inside `with` to the file can be closed and not kept unnecessarily opened.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The issue lies with **pointers**.
Your `dictionary(data_list)` is currently capable of directly modifying your `dic_result` variable.

Your `while` loop is actually appending like so internally:

```
[ 
  <@address of "dic_result">, 
  <@address of "dic_result">, 
  <@address of "dic_result">, ...
]
```

When you call `print()`, it retrieves the value from the @address in memory.

## Solution

Return a new 'copy' and append that to your list instead.

You will need to modify your `dictionary()` function and `while` loop like so:

```py
list_result=[]

# combines the headers and the values into dictionaries with the function 'dictionary'
def dictionary(data_list):
    dic_result={} # <------ create and init locally 
    for header, value in zip(headers,data_list):
        dic_result[header]=value
    print(dic_result)
    return dic_result # <-- return a new 'copy'


# Then I applied a while loop into this function to all the different lines and the result of each line is a dictionary.
contador2=0
while contador2 < len(file1_lines):
    try:
        temp_dict = dictionary(file1_full[contador2]) # <---- output from function
        list_result.append(temp_dict)
        contador2=contador2+1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

You essentially already have the correct logic, just `return` instead of unintendedly modifying them. You should format your code like this in the future:

```py
# Imports
import os
import urllib.request

# RETRIEVE some data from a URL
url1 = '<some url string>'
os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url1,'./data/datos1.txt')

# USE with TO READ data ONCE
with open ('./data/datos1.txt') as file1:
   file1_lines = file1.readlines() # <----- read once. That's it.

# TRANSFORM data
count = 0
file1_full = []
while count < len(file1_line):
    # some actions here
    count += 1

# COMPUTE your dictionaries
count = 0
list_result = []
dic_result = {}
while count < len(file1_line):
    # some actions here
    dic_result = dictionary_function(param1, param2)
    list_result.append(dic_result)
    
    count += 1

print(list_result)
```

I'm a bit confused as to how you're debugging. Though I get that learning a new language is always fun and different. So keep up the good work!

Edit: Hope this clears it up! I forgot to attach the actual answer, but hinted at the answer in the lower part of the code.